# MS Access VBA to Open an Excel file then go to Column I and send command F2 and Enter

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have an access program that reads in a customer file and provides dates on when orders will be shipped.  The file needs to be fed back into the customers portal in a specific format.   When I change the date in the file to be fed back I have to go to the shipdate field and hit F2 then enter for the file to upload successfully.   often there are over 1000 lines that this needs to be done to.   When I run the code from access to export the table and open excel I receive the error

> "Object does not support this property or method"

Everything does change to **BOLD** however if I try to do a sendkey to the entire spreadsheet or a specific cell, I get the error...
Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have tried about everything and ready to pull my hair out.

```
.Range(.cells(1, 1), .cells(lngMaxRow + 1, lngMaxCol)).Font.Bold = True
.Range(.cells(1, 1), .cells(lngMaxRow + 1, lngMaxCol)).SendKeys "{F2}", True
.Range("I12").SendKeys "{F2}", True
```

Comment: So you need to be on a specific cell when F2 is pressed?

Comment: No I just need to hit f2 on every cell in the I Column... I chose I12 as a test because that had a date that failed when we try the upload to the customer portal.

Comment: Sorry guess I should explain my question more, when F2 is pressed does a cell have to be selected. For instance if you just press F2 at the same spot in the code, but don't change what cell is selected, will that make a difference? Or does the individual cells need to be selected when F2 is pressed?

Comment: Well I believe it would need to be selected.. we have tried everything from reformatting the column to cutting and pasting just values, etc.. nothing works for the file upload to the customers portal.   So we literally have to go into the ship Date column and hit f2 then enter for the entire file (often 1000 lines) then save it then upload it.

Comment: @TMoon  I believe that in Excel the F2 just puts the active cell into edit mode-- you can then change it.  Is that what F2 is doing for you?  What is in the cell before you press F2? and what is it changed to after you press F2?  What part of the date is causing failure?  What part of the program creates that date?

Comment: It is very strange on how this file is reacting.   I read in a file from their portal then check various thing in our system then determine an Estimated ship Date if one is not already present in the file.   When the date gets put into the table then extracted to Excel it is in the format of MM/DD/YY.   However when we upload it to the customers portal, all records where we put in a date bomb out on the upload.

Comment: We have tried everything in excel to changing the format of the columns to cutting the data and pasting as values, etc.. nothing works except selecting the sell and hitting F2.   we have noticed that it will change a date of 05/30/16 to 5/30/16 once the cell is selected and F2 is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Basically sendkeys isn't a method of the range object. Sendkeys just sends strokes to applications. Try the method with this code:

```
Sub test()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range("I12").Select
    Do
        Application.SendKeys ("{F2}")
        ActiveCell(2, 1).Select
    Loop Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
End Sub
```

Before this will work successfully, you may need to make sure that your Excel workbook is the active application, on top of all else.

EDIT: You explained it wouldn't work, yes it's because you're launching from Access, so those steps need to be aimed at Excel. I used a sample provided by Trevor G [here](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=251416) to build an example. This will get us closer to the goal, but I don't think it's a total solution yet:

```
Option Compare Database

Sub excelExport()
    'Step 1: Declare variables
    Dim MyDatabase As DAO.Database
    Dim MyQueryDef As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim MyRecordset As DAO.Recordset
    'Step 2: Identify the database and query
    Set MyDatabase = CurrentDb
    Set MyQueryDef = MyDatabase.QueryDefs("Table1 Query") 'Query name in the database
    'Step 3: Open the query
    Set MyRecordset = MyQueryDef.OpenRecordset

    'Step 4: Create Excel
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    objShell.AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"

    With xlApp
        .Visible = True
        .Workbooks.Add
        .Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        .Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
        'Step 5: Copy the recordset to Excel
        .ActiveSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset MyRecordset
        'Step 6: Add column heading names to the spreadsheet
        'For i = 1 To MyRecordset.Fields.Count
        'xlApp.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).Value = MyRecordset.Fields(i - 1).Name
        'Next i
        .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

        .Range("A2").Select

        Do
            .Application.SendKeys ("{F2}")
            .Application.SendKeys ("{ENTER}")
            .ActiveCell(2, 1).Select
        Loop Until .ActiveCell.Value = ""

    End With
End Sub
```

I found that when F2 is first pressed, Excel becomes locked and no further code seems to run... but hitting enter once seems to help it along. I think to make the "F2+enter" loop work though, we may need to create and run an external VBScript (that can send the keys indiscriminately). However, when I tried to do this, I struggled to get the VBS to successfully bring Excel to front, which seems to be a common problem.

Comment: Thank you for the very quick reply.   I have tried the solution however I still get the "Object does not support this property or method"  could it be because I am launching Excel from an access form?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add references when working in Excel.

When in Visual Basic...Tools > References > Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library.

Note - your installed Excel version might show differently.

Comment: The reference to the Excel object library is only required if using 'early binding' and there is nothing in the question to suppose they are, or that the lack of reference is related to the problem.